# Laravel subdomain routing alternative

Tags: php, laravel

We're in the progress of changing a portal system. It used to have 1 company using it, but it needs to be changed so that multiple company's can use it. Each company will get it's own subdomain based on a slug of the company name, so the subdomain will be dynamic.

Laravel has the following code on subdomain routing in the docs (Changed to my example:

```
Route::domain('{company}.portal.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function (Company $company, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

What I don't like about this is that I need to add `Company $company` as argument to all current routes methods (60+), while a lot of them don't even need the subdomain information.

An alternative I am considering is to add company middleware to the company subdomain routing group. In the middleware I check if the company has a model with the same slug. And I create 2 static functions on the company model to get/set the current company. So inside the controllers/views I would get the current company with something like `Company::getCurrent()`

Would this be a good practice, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Store in the ***session*** may be?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why would that be better, since you have to see if the subdomain is still the same (People can switch from company's in theory) you have to check to company every request anyway. So what benefits would the session store have over the static getter setters methods?